# problems with ctypes in python 2.7.3

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes

Some problems occurs when I study ctypes.My envirement is python 2.7.3 on win10 system.The details of the problem is :I make a dll called a.dll dependency on sqlite3.dll,and I compile sqlite3.dll with source code(I modify the source code to increment the limit of attachment database,default is 10,i updated it to 30).When I use ctypes to call my function in a.dll,i found there is an error occurs:the attachment database limit is 10.I guess the program dosen't load my sqlite3.dll,but load the python's defsult sqlite3.dll.how to fixed it？

Comment: Why not give your dll another name?

Comment: you mean I rename sqlite3.dll compiled by my self to another name e.g. xx.dll?